# How to determine weight dimension for input tensor of Rank-3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to design an Autoencoder for activity classification for 3-channel input (Tri-axial accelerometer data).

The input tensor is of shape `[None,200,3]` ([Batch size, window size, number of channels]) and in the first layer, I want to simply reduce the dimension of input layer to `[None,150,3]`. Here is the code for creating placeholders and the first layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def denseLayer(inputVal,weight,bias):
    return tf.nn.relu((tf.matmul(inputVal,weight)+bias))


x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,200,3]) #Input tensor
wIn = tf.get_variable(name='wIn',initializer=tf.truncated_normal(stddev=0.1,dtype=tf.float32,shape=[200,150]))

bIn = tf.get_variable(name='bIn',initializer=tf.constant(value = 0.1,shape=[150,3],dtype=tf.float32))


firstLayer = denseLayer(x,weight=wIn,bias=bIn)
```

This code will, of course, result in an error (due to the difference in rank between `x` and `wIn`) and i am unable to determine the **shape of `wIn` variable** to get the desired shape of `firstLayer` that is `[None,150,3]`.

Here is how the final network should look (simplified version with lesser layers):
[image: Autoencoder]

Comment: What you are trying to do is a bit unusual, since typically you use "flat" feature vectors (e.g. a 600-element input vector in your case, instead of 200 3-element vectors, and a 450-element output vector, instead of 150 3-element vector). So, for one given example, you have an input `[200, 3]` and want an output `[150, 3]`, but what is the connectivity of the network? For example, should the "x" coordinate of each output vector be connected to all "x", "y" and "z" coordinates of the input vectors, or only to the "x" coordinates of the input?

Comment: @jdehesa I have added a diagram to clear the confusion ('x' coordinate should only be connected to the 'x' coordinate to successfully recreate the input at the output layer)

Comment: I see, I appreciate the effort with the diagram. Just one more thing, for each layer, do you want to use the same set of weights for the three coordinates (like having a single layer that is used three times)? Or you want to have 'x' weights, 'y' weights and 'z' weights (like having three "parallel" layers)?

Comment: @jdehesa I believe using different weights for each axis will improve the performance as opposed to constraining weight parameter to have the same value on each axis. But does it mean that i have to create 3 `weight variables` for each axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def denseLayer(inputVal, weight, bias):
    # Each input "channel" uses the corresponding set of weights
    value = tf.einsum('nic,ijc->njc', inputVal, weight) + bias
    return tf.nn.relu(value)
#Input tensor
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 200, 3])
# Weights and biases have three "channels" each
wIn = tf.get_variable(name='wIn',
                      shape=[200, 150, 3],
                      initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
bIn = tf.get_variable(name='bIn',
                      shape=[150, 3],
                      initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.1))
firstLayer = denseLayer(x, weight=wIn, bias=bIn)
print(firstLayer)
# Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(?, 150, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Here `wIn` can be seen as three sets of `[200, 150]` parameters that are applied to each input channel. I think [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum) is the easiest way to implement that in this case.